# Creating a simple PHP interpreter in Visual C++

Tags: php, c++, visual-c++, interpreter, embedding

When I look through the source code files I have downloaded from the PHP website, I get lost so easy. What I would like to do is obtain all the source code needed to create a Console application that takes your PHP code and executes it. I would also like to maybe be able to add C++ functions and calll them from PHP. I have done this quite simply with Lua on my *Mac* via Xcode, but I don't think it will be that easy using PHP on a different system using a different program.

Comment: Whats wrong with PHP's interpreter? ala php.exe

Comment: what is your use case i guess? There is a php.exe you can get that will do exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write PHP extensions using C (or C++, I suppose) to expose libraries to PHP, but PHP isn't designed to be embedded in applications other than web servers.

Comment: Ok, I guess my question, now, is how can I add extensions to PHP within WampServer?

Comment: Load them in `php.ini` using `extension = myextension.dll`.

Comment: You can run PHP from console or even create desktops applications with it. Even though it isn't widely used it doesn't mean it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Little 2019 update about  @duskwuff comment.

PHP8 will have JIT compiler, so, no, PHP will no longer be used only for web.

[image: Description]

As you can see on image, PHP8 compiler is faster than Java, C compiler etc.

Comment: What do these numbers mean? Where do they come from?

Comment: What does these number mean ? Not sure if you are a programer but the compilation time mean that harder and longer process will be much easier to be done, like big ressource calculation etc .I can't tell you the exact source since i made alot of search about the new PHP8 and all i can tell is just googling "PHP8 JIT comparison" and you will see that PHP8 is a big thing.

Comment: Edit: just saw you are C++ or Python dev. There's no way you will approove that but still, benchmark is a benchmark and all benchmark comparing PHP8 to other language compiler told that PHP kill every other compiler. So in 2019 telling that PHP is "dead" and only for webdev is totally bias.

Comment: "... compilation time mean that harder and longer process will be much easier to be done, like big ressource calculation ..." So your numbers are compilation times? Are they important for running a program?

Comment: My question was not about the meaning of a benchmark. It was about which task, source code, compiler options, hardware, cache usage, .... How can they be compared between the different compilers? Without that I consider the benchmark results basically useless.